# How to fix Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, build

I have built a flutter app. I can run the app in xCode simulator without no problem. But when I try to archive it, it throws the PhaseScriptExecution error. I have tried flutter clean then reinstall the pods again. But to no avail.

Here is my flutter doctor result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale
    en-MY)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at /Users/admin/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (6 days ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Users/admin/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

And this is the output of flutter build ios

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/hd/glkbj0nj6ll0c_cgglq_cx400000gq/T/flutter_tools.sxyetd/flutt
        er_ios_build_temp_dirhsbaOo/temporary_xcresult_bundle


    Failed to package /Users/admin/StudioProjects/mymaikapp.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/hd/glkbj0nj6ll0c_cgglq_cx400000gq/T/flutter_tools.sxyetd/flutt
        er_ios_build_temp_dirhsbaOo/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Encountered error while building for device.
```

If it would help, I ran the command flutter run --verbose and put the log here, if it would help tracing what is the error, but I couldn't find it.

[flutter run verbose output](https://pastebin.com/yhdt8pL1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might try building the project in Xcode, if you haven't already, and see if you find more details on the script failure in the error logs there

Comment: @Micheal Horn, the error when build using xcode is command phasescriptexecution failed with a non zero exit code

Comment: There's usually some more detailed logs on the error in the issue navigator - Are you able to see anything there?

Comment: At the very least, you should be able to see the command that was attempted right before the failure was encountered

Comment: This is the output when I tried to build in xcode. https://pastebin.com/sdYXjvQN

Comment: Ok great - Looks like the error is happening in a custom Run Script phase - If you know how to find those, you can check each for errors, or you can post the code back here

Comment: If you don't know, you can find them under the build phases tab, as in the link here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-custom-scripts-during-a-build?changes=_8

Comment: Hi Micheal, here is the repo containing the code https://github.com/HellRyder43/mymaikapp

Comment: Hmm, I had no trouble building an archive of your project - My Xcode version is 13.4.  I would recommend making sure you have the latest xcode, running `flutter clean`, then `cd ios`, `pod deintegrate` — make sure the Pods folder is completely removed — then `cd ..`, `flutter pub get`, `flutter build ipa --release`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and still getting the same error. Right now, I am using codemagic and integrate with app store connect. Not sure how to fix the issue on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I downloaded flutter 2.10.5 stable, archive it at the same folder with flutter 3.0.2. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEFD1.png) and then change the flutter sdk path to flutter 2.10.5.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yo0t.png) Run pub get and then archived it.